# Implementing more complicated django search involving distance

Tags: django

I'm trying to implement the following search bar, where each entry between brackets is a input box that can be filled out by the user.

[keyword] [number] miles from [store-name]

This search enables the user to search for items that match the keyword in all the stores that are the specified number of miles away from their specified store. All fields are optional -- just keyword alone searches all stores, just store-name alone searches for all items within that store, number and store name searches all items within that distance of store, etc. If keyword + number are inputted without store-name, number will be ignored. If just number is inputted, it will also be ignored.

Right now, I have the following model for distances. All the relevant distances are already calculated and stored in the database.

```
class Distance(models.Model):
    from_zip = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    to_zip = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    #distance from the from_zip to the to_zip
    distance_in_miles = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=8)
```

I also have another model that matches zipcodes to store names.

I looked into a few different python search packages, such as django-ajax-search and django-watson, but don't think they are what I'm looking for. Both would let me easily implement a search over a model, but I don't see how I can incorporate the extra two search fields (distance, store name). Does anyone have any recommendations for me about how to go about this, or recommended packages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using django haystack with elasticsearch. It might be more set up for now, but in the long term it should be more scalable and faster.

http://haystacksearch.org/
http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/spatial.html